# How to get href attribute of links and set it to href of next sibling using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, href

I have a page with a number of dynamically generated links (through Liquid, it's a Shopify site) and they all have the same class.  Each link is associated with another link (an image) and I'd like to apply the `href` attribute of each link to its associated second link.

I imagine I need to pull them all into an array object, then distribute them in the same order, but I'm lost.  Any suggestions?

An example in HTML would be:

```
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-1"></a>
<a href="" class="empty-link"><img src="" alt=""></a>   
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-2"></a>
<a href="" class="empty-link"><img src="" alt=""></a>   
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-3"></a>
<a href="" class="empty-link"><img src="" alt=""></a>   
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-4"></a>
<a href="" class="empty-link"><img src="" alt=""></a>   
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-5"></a>
<a href="" class="empty-link"><img src="" alt=""></a>
```

Basically, I want to grab the href value of each `.initial-link` and apply them to their corresponding `.empty-link` href.

Thanks

Comment: It would help us a lot to see your HTML

Comment: how do you know what link belongs to what img ?

Comment: Ah, okay, just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a loop, select the next element using `next()` use `attr()` to get and append the url

```
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-1"></a>
<a href="" class="empty-link"><img src="" alt=""></a>   
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-2"></a>
<a href="" class="empty-link"><img src="" alt=""></a>   
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-3"></a>
<a href="" class="empty-link"><img src="" alt=""></a>   
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-4"></a>
<a href="" class="empty-link"><img src="" alt=""></a>   
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-5"></a>
<a href="" class="empty-link"><img src="" alt=""></a>
```

js:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.initial-link').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).next().attr('href',href);
      });
    })
```

demo:

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.initial-link').each(function() {
         var href = $(this).attr('href');
         $(this).next().attr('href', href);
       });
     })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-1">1</a>
<a href="" class="empty-link">e1
  <img src="" alt="">
</a>
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-2">2</a>
<a href="" class="empty-link">e2
  <img src="" alt="">
</a>
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-3">3</a>
<a href="" class="empty-link">e3
  <img src="" alt="">
</a>
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-4">4</a>
<a href="" class="empty-link">e4
  <img src="" alt="">
</a>
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-5">5</a>
<a href="" class="empty-link">e5
  <img src="" alt="">
</a>
```

or loop over the empty link and select the href of the previous link (initial-link) using `prev()` and `attr()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.empty-link').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).prev().attr('href');
        $(this).attr('href',href);
      });
    })
```

demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.empty-link').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).prev().attr('href');
        $(this).attr('href',href);
      });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-1">1</a>
<a href="" class="empty-link">e1
  <img src="" alt="">
</a>
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-2">2</a>
<a href="" class="empty-link">e2
  <img src="" alt="">
</a>
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-3">3</a>
<a href="" class="empty-link">e3
  <img src="" alt="">
</a>
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-4">4</a>
<a href="" class="empty-link">e4
  <img src="" alt="">
</a>
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-5">5</a>
<a href="" class="empty-link">e5
  <img src="" alt="">
</a>
```

Note:: remove the empty href from the initial-link you already  have a href attribute

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the links and grab the href and then pass the href to the next link. Note that I added a1 - e2 as link text to demonstrate that each link now has the href. (the 1's are the initial hrefs and the 2's are teh ones given by the function. I also cleared out hte empty hrefs on your initial links.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  $('.initial-link').each(function(){
    var linkHref = $(this).attr('href');
   $(this).next('.empty-link').attr('href',linkHref)
  });
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-1">a1</a>
<a class="empty-link"><img src="" alt="">a2</a>   
<a  class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-2">b1</a>
<a class="empty-link"><img src="" alt="">b1</a>   
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-3">c1</a>
<a class="empty-link"><img src="" alt="">c1</a>   
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-4">d1</a>
<a class="empty-link"><img src="" alt="">d2</a>   
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-5">e1</a>
<a class="empty-link"><img src="" alt="">e2</a>
```

Comment: Intitially I was using an array - since hte OP  referenced one in the question - but then amended my answer to alter the href using .next()

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate all `.empty-link` using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and get `href` attribute of previous link (`.initial-link`) in loop.

```js
$(".empty-link").attr("href", function(){
    return $(this).prev(".initial-link").attr("href");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-1">initial</a>
<a href="" class="empty-link">
  <img src="" alt="">empty
</a>   
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-2">initial</a>
<a href="" class="empty-link">
  <img src="" alt="">empty
</a>   
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-3">initial</a>
<a href="" class="empty-link">
  <img src="" alt="">empty
</a>   
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-4">initial</a>
<a href="" class="empty-link">
  <img src="" alt="">empty
</a>   
<a class="initial-link" href="http://some-link-5">initial</a>
<a href="" class="empty-link">
  <img src="" alt="">empty
</a>
```